# Oracle SQL query to get the sum of elements for an employee

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with multiple values of elements for an element with corresponding input values:

```
EE   ELEMENT_NAME     RESULT_VALUE   EFFECTIVE DATE   INPUT VALUE
10   REGULAR RETRO    3457           10-APR-2023      earning
10   REGULAR RETTO    -3454          10-APR-2023      earning
10   REGULAR SALAR    34000          10-APR-2023      Pay
11   REGULAR SALAR    670000         10-APR-2023      earning
11   DENTAL SALAR     100            10-APR-2023      Pay
11   HEALTH SALAR     2000           10-APR-2023      Pay
11   Car     SALAR    2000           10-APR-2023      Pay
12   EE       RETRO   -3000          10-APR-2023      Pay
12   REGULAR RETRO    1000           10-APR-2023      earning
12   REGULAR RETRO    -890           10-APR-2023      earning
12   Tax RETRO        -890           10-APR-2023      earning
```

The required output is:

```
EE   REGULAR_RETRO   REGULAR_SALAR   DENTAL_SALAR   HEALTH_SALAR   EE_RETRO
10   3               34000
11                   670000          100            2000
12   110                                                           -3000
```

The below query I am using is only for specific elements that I am defining in "where clause" of my query, but I am getting multiple rows for the same employee although I am using group by.
And the output is also not summing up the retros values (regular retros) and is giving repeated rows instead.

The query I am using is:

```
select ee person_number,
    case when peen.element_name in 'REGULAR RETRO'
    then sum (RESULT_VALUE) REGULAR_RETRO,
    case when peen.element_name in 'REGULAR SALAR'
    then sum (RESULT_VALUE) REGULAR_SALAR,
    case when peen.element_name in 'DENTAL SALAR'
    then sum (RESULT_VALUE) DENTAL_SALAR,
    case when peen.element_name in 'HEALTH SALAR'
    then sum (RESULT_VALUE) HEALTH_SALAR,
    case when peen.element_name in 'EE       RETRO'
    then sum (RESULT_VALUE) EE_RETRO

FROM
PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F PAPF
PER_ELEMENT_NAME PEEN,
PEr_ELEMENT_TYPE PET
WHERE
PAPF.PERSON_ID = PEEN.PERSON_ID
AND PEEN.ELEMENT_ID = PET.ELEMENT_ID
AND PET.INPUT_VALUE IN ('Pay','Earning')
and peen.element_name in
(
'REGULAR SALAR',
'DENTAL SALAR',
'HEALTH SALAR',
'EE       RETRO',
'REGULAR RETRO'
)
 group by person_number,
 peen.element_name
```

Comment: Why do two of the items in "ELEMENT_NAME" have TABs in them (7th and 8th row)? (A mix of TABs and spaces.) [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9eac4184-150b-4b99-b4fa-3e7c302a13d4/view-source).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using the conditional aggregation using `group by` and `sum()` :

```
select EE,
       sum(case when ELEMENT_NAME = 'REGULAR RETRO' then RESULT_VALUE else 0 end) as REGULAR_RETRO,
       sum(case when ELEMENT_NAME = 'REGULAR SALAR' then RESULT_VALUE else 0 end) as REGULAR_SALAR,
       sum(case when ELEMENT_NAME = 'DENTAL SALAR' then RESULT_VALUE else 0 end) as DENTAL_SALAR,
       sum(case when ELEMENT_NAME = 'HEALTH SALAR' then RESULT_VALUE else 0 end) as HEALTH_SALAR,
       sum(case when ELEMENT_NAME = 'EE RETRO' then RESULT_VALUE else 0 end) as EE_RETRO
from mytable
group by EE
```

Result :

| EE | REGULAR_RETRO | REGULAR_SALAR | DENTAL_SALAR | HEALTH_SALAR | EE_RETRO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 3 | 34000 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 11 | 0 | 670000 | 100 | 2000 | 0 |
| 12 | 110 | 0 | 0 | 0 | -3000 |

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/TFzPOADX)

Answer (score 0):

Fix the syntax of the CASE in your query and remove the peen.element_name from the "group by" should solve the problem.